# Cyclic calculation - replace for loop with dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I've write a code with a for loop and I want to make it more efficient with dataframe.
The problem concerns stock management: at the end of a period, the stock is equal to the final stock at the end of the previous period (as well as some other variables).

This is very simple to implement with a for loop but I don't see how to model it with a data frame.

Here is my for loop with comments at each lines. At the end I print the dataframe I want.

```
library(tidyverse)

H = 10  # horizon
period = c(0:H) # here, period of 11 days

# data
demand = rep(25, H+1) # daily demand amount
order = c(rep(0, 5), 200, rep(0, 5)) # 200 units will be delivered on day 5
ongoing = c(rep(0, 5), 50, rep(0, 5)) # 50 " __________________________ "
delivery = order + ongoing # total deliveries

#initial_values
beta = .5 # backorder coefficient : proportion of the demand that will be repeated 
          # the following day if it is not satisfied on the same day
initial_stock = 15
initial_backorder = 0  # backorder : total demand that will be repeated the following dat
start_stock = c(initial_stock, H+1)
backorder = c(initial_backorder, H+1)


#_sat = _satisfied
#_unsat = _unsatisfied
backorder_sat = rep(0, H+1)
backorder_unsat = rep(0, H+1)
demand_sat = rep(0, H+1)
demand_unsat = rep(0, H+1)
demand_rep = rep(0, H+1)
lost_sales = rep(0, H+1)
end_stock = rep(0, H+1)

for(i in 1:(H+1))
{
  backorder_sat[i] = min(backorder[i], start_stock[i] + delivery[i]) # we first satisfy backorder with qty available
  backorder_unsat[i] = backorder[i] - backorder_sat[i] # if stock+delivery < backorder ==> unsatisfied backorder
  demand_sat[i] = min(demand[i], start_stock[i] + delivery[i] - backorder_sat[i]) # we satisfy demand with remaining qty 
  demand_unsat[i] = demand[i] - demand_sat[i] # if remaining qty < demand ==> unsatified demand
  demand_rep[i] = floor(beta * demand_unsat[i]) # proportion demand that will be repeated next day (consumers will return to store)
  lost_sales[i] = demand_unsat[i] - demand_rep[i] # rest of unsat demand is lost
  end_stock[i] = start_stock[i] + delivery[i] - backorder_sat[i] - demand_sat[i] # final stock of the day
  if(i < H+1){ # update stock & backorder for the next day
    backorder[i+1] = demand_rep[i] + backorder_unsat[i]
    start_stock[i+1] = end_stock[i]
  }
}

dyn = data.frame(period, start_stock, order, ongoing, 
                backorder, backorder_sat, backorder_unsat, 
                demand, demand_sat, demand_unsat, demand_rep, 
                lost_sales, end_stock)%>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "period")

view(dyn)
```

Comment: A loop is probably the best way to do this. I doubt this can be vectorized.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. When you say you want a data.frame, are you saying you'd rather use one object with columns instead of 7 individual variables, within the loop? As commented above, this can't be vectorized, because it relies on the previous states.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that's what I wanted to know.